# Jfrog insight service is not running

Tags: jfrog-mission-control

I am trying to install jfrog insights by following official documentation of jfrog "https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Insight#InstallingInsight-ManualDebianInstallation"[As you see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOGw0.jpg)

Installation debian package . Elastic search is running as well as PostgreSQL is also runnning

Comment: Can you please check the log files and share the error log messages so that it will be helpful to understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi JayanthSuresh

Below error i have seen in the log file 

Could not resolve config value for key 'router.serviceRegistry.url', although it was just returned as part of all keys... Ignoring.
Could not initialize configuration: service registry URL could not be resolved (please configure the JFrog Platform Deployment URL explicitly, e.g. using the environment variable: JF_SHARED_JFROGURL)